# At the time of Convertion in Gridview's TemplateField object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FollowUpDate">
       <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("followupdate")).ToString("d") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am using this type to Covert the datetime format into date only.It works fine when the date is available in MSSQL database.
But when the field is empty it shows
**Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.**

```
Line 91: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("followupdate")).ToString("d") %>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"  comes
>   if you are there are null values stored in the database against the
>   fields followupdate. At first you need to check if a value exists in
>   those fields for example if followupdate is not DBNULL. After that you
>   need to do that (only if they are not DBNULL). You can even bind the
>   data in RowDatabound.

Try like this

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FollowUpDate">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% # Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("followupdate")==DBNull.Value ? System.DateTime.Now : (Eval("followupdate"))).ToString("d") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: it means you have missed any syntax

Comment: @SandipSarkar I have update solution, Please check now

Comment: `<% # Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("followupdate")==DBNull.Value ? System.DateTime.Now : (Eval("followupdate"))).ToString("d") %>`
**How to left the space blank in the grid view,if i don't want to show the current date**
@Vignesh Kumar

Answer (score 0):

This error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"  comes if you are there are null values stored in the database against the fields followupdate. At first you need to check if a value exists in those fields for example if followupdate is not DBNULL. After that you need to do that computation followupdate(only if they are not DBNULL). You can even bind the data in RowDatabound.

Comment: Yes I have NULL values.
It doesn't shows any error when the field in NOT-NULL.
What I have to do to Handel this error?